# magento 2 how to enable money order Payment from Specific Customer

Tags: magento2, frontend

magento 2 how to enable money order Payment from Specific Customer(B to B Customers)

Comment: Hello Trilok can you please write in details?

Comment: Hi as i need the payment method Check / Money Order should be displayed to only particular Customer group that is (B to B Customers)

Comment: Yeah its an paid extension.. Evince Development

Comment: Yes it's fullfill your requirements you can purchase it.

Comment: Can you post link again Evince Development